# Find current cursor position for textbox with htmleditorextender

Tags: htmleditorextender

I have been using insertAtCaret to insert text at the current cursor position for textboxes however when the textbox becomes associated with an htmleditorextender it fails (I guess because the textbox is now a child element of the htmleditorextender or maybe it creates an iframe?).

Here is my insertAtCaret javascript that works fine when there's no htmleditorextender. The textbox associated with an htmleditorextender is txtEmailBody. Do I need to reference txtEmailBody differently?

```
function insertAtCaret(text) {
     var txtarea = document.getElementById("<%=txtEmailBody.ClientID%>")
     var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
     var strPos = 0;
     var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
     if (br == "ie") {
         txtarea.focus();
         var range = document.selection.createRange();
         range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
         strPos = range.text.length;
     }
     else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

     var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
     var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
     txtarea.value = front + text + back;
     strPos = strPos + text.length;
     if (br == "ie") {
         txtarea.focus();
         var range = document.selection.createRange();
         range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
         range.moveStart('character', strPos);
         range.moveEnd('character', 0);
         range.select();
     }
     else if (br == "ff") {
         txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
         txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
         txtarea.focus();
     }
     txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;

 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: this will insert text at certain position but I still need to find the current cursor pos so that the txt can be inserted at that point: <script type = "text/javascript" >

               function insertTextAtCursor(txt) {
                   var position = 5;
   
var current = $find("<%= HtmlEditorExtender3.ClientID %>")._editableDiv.innerHTML;
//alert(current.substring(0, position))
var endVal = current.substring(position);
var newValue = current.substring(0, position) + txt + endVal;
$find("<%= HtmlEditorExtender3.ClientID %>")._editableDiv.innerHTML = newValue;
        }
        </script>

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here http://jsfiddle.net/VzbYJ/32/

Just change reference to the htmleditorextender as follows:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
        var el = $find("<%= HtmlEditorExtender3.ClientID %>")._editableDiv;
        pasteHtmlAtCaret("Some <b>random</b> text", el);
    });
```